# ¿Cómo usar anulación (Polimorfismo) en C++?

Tags: c++

Lo que quiero es poder anular las funciones de la clase suma
y sustituirlas por las funciones de la clase loop.
Esto tiene que ver con Polimorfismo.

En este código explico mejor la pregunta (ver el comentario):

```cpp
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class suma{
    public:
        void leer(int &a, int &b, int &c);
        void calculo(int &a, int &b, int &c);
        void escribir(int &a, int &b, int &c);
};
class loop: public suma{
    public:
        void leer(int &a, int &b, int &c);
        void calculo(int &a, int &b, int &c);
        void escribir(int &a, int &b, int &c);
};

main(){
    int a, b, c;

    suma s;
    loop l;



    // Anulación <---- 
    cout << "Se supone que con esto anulo." << endl;
    s = l; // <---- Se supone que así anulo las funciones del objeto s
           //       y le asigno las funciones del objeto l
    s.leer(a, b, c);
    s.calculo(a, b, c);
    s.escribir(a, b, c);
}

void suma::leer(int &a, int &b, int &c){
    cout << "SUMA" << endl;
    cout << "Ingresa numero a: ";
    cin >> a;
    cout << "Ingresa numero b: ";
    cin >> b;
}
void suma::calculo(int &a, int &b, int &c){
    c = a + b;
}
void suma::escribir(int &a, int &b, int &c){
    cout << a << " + " << b << " = " << c << endl;
}

void loop::leer(int &a, int &b, int &c){
    cout << "LOOP" << endl;
    cout << "Ingresa numero a: ";
    cin >> a;
    cout << "Ingresa numero b: ";
    cin >> b;
}
void loop::calculo(int &a, int &b, int &c){
    c = a * b;
}

void loop::escribir(int &a, int &b, int &c){
    cout << a << " * " << b << " = " << c << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Aparte de lo comentado por @rnd hay otra característica de C++ a tener en cuenta: la ocultación.

Si tu tienes una clase base en la que declaras varios métodos que pueden ser, o no, virtuales:

```
class Base
{
public:
  void func()
  { std::cout << "Base::func()\n"; }

  void func(int)
  { std::cout << "Base::func(int)\n"; }
};
```

Y posteriormente, al heredar de ella sobreescribes algunos de esos métodos:

```
class Derivada
{
public:
  void func()
  { std::cout << "Derivada::func()\n"; }
};
```

¿Qué efecto tiene esto sobre el programa? Lo vemos con un ejemplo:

```
int main()
{
  Base b;
  b.func();  // Base::func()
  b.func(4); // Base::func(int)

  Derivada d;
  d.func();  // Derivada::func()
  d.func(4); // ERROR de compilación
}
```

La declaración de `func` en la clase derivada va a ocultar, por defecto, todas las sobrecargas que puedan existir en su clase base. Hay mecanismos para *importar* las funciones que necesitemos de la clase base pero por defecto quedarán ocultas.

Ahora, ¿Qué sucede si, como en el ejemplo, no hemos declarado la función base como `virtual`?

```
int main()
{
  Derivada* d = new Derivada;
  Base* b = d; // Polimorfismo

  d->func(); // Derivada::func()
  b->func(); // Base::func()

  delete d;
}
```

Al no estar etiquetada la función como `virtual`, el compilador no sustituye una función por otra, sino que dependiendo del contexto (en este caso el tipo de puntero que estemos utilizano) se llamará a una función o a otra.

Sin embargo, si declaramos la función como virtual la cosa cambia:

```
class Base
{
public:
  virtual void func()
  { std::cout << "Base::func()\n"; }
};

class Derivada
{
public:
  void func() override
  { std::cout << "Derivada::func()\n"; }
};

int main()
{
  Base b;
  Derivada d;

  Base* ptr = &b;
  ptr->func(); // Base::func()

  ptr = &d;
  ptr->func(); // Derivada::func()
}
```

Al declarar la función de la clase padre como `virtual` permitimos que el compilador pueda descartar la función base y sustituirla por la versión proporcionada por la clase derivada.

Como nota adicional, el modificador `override` (disponible a partir del estándar C++11) obliga al compilador a comprobar que la función en cuestión va a sobreescribir a una función de la clase padre (que debe ser virtual). Si no se cumplen estas condiciones el compilador mostrará un error. Que el compilador compruebe estas cosas por si sólo es algo que evita muchos errores a la hora de programar:

```
class Base
{
public:
  void func()

  virtual void func2();

  virtual void func3(int);
};

class Derivada
{
public:
  // ERROR -> la función base no es virtual
  void func() override;

  // ERROR -> no existe fnuc2, debería ser func2
  void fnuc2() override; 

  // ERROR -> no existe un método virtual func3 sin parámetros
  // en la clase padre
  void func3() override;

  // OK
  void func3(int) override;
};
```

Un saludo.

Comment: cabe destacar que override existe desde c++11.

Comment: cierto, en este mensaje se me ha pasado

Comment: Gracias a todos por sus respuestas, sin duda todas funcionaron pero mi profesor sólo aceptó este método como "correcto" para su trabajo.

Answer (score 3):

Sin duda las respuestas de [eferion](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/10527/2742) y [rnd](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/10514/2742) son válidas; pero ambas usan memoria dinámica para algo en que no sería necesario; además tampoco cumple con la sintáxis que expresas en tu pregunta:

```
s = l; // <---- Se supone que así anulo las funciones del objeto s
       //       y le asigno las funciones del objeto l
```

Existe una manera de conseguir la sintaxis que expresas en tu pregunta sin necesidad de usar herencia (así escribimos menos) ni punteros (así evitamos usar`->`, lo cuál es más cómodo) ni memoria dinámica (así el programa es ligeramente más rápido)<sup>1</sup>, sería usando punteros a funciones; empezaremos definiendo los tipos de las funciones a usar:

```
using lectura   = void(int &, int &, int &);
using operacion = void(int &, int &, int &);
using escritura = void(int &, int &, int &);
```

Y acto seguido definimos un objeto que use estas funciones:

```
struct operador
{
    lectura *leer;
    operacion *calculo;
    escritura *escribir;
};
```

Teniendo las funciones adecuadas, podemos configurar nuestro `operador` a nuestro antojo:

```
void lee_suma(int &a, int &b, int &c) {
    std::cout << "\nSUMA\nIngresa numero a: ";
    std::cin >> a;
    std::cout << "\nIngresa numero b: ";
    std::cin >> b;
}

void suma(int &a, int &b, int &c) {
    c = a + b;
}

void muestra_suma(int &a, int &b, int &c) {
    std::cout << '\n' << a << " + " << b << " = " << c << '\n';
}

void lee_loop(int &a, int &b, int &c) {
    std::cout << "\nLOOP\nIngresa numero a: ";
    std::cin >> a;
    std::cout << "\nIngresa numero b: ";
    std::cin >> b;
}

void loop(int &a, int &b, int &c) {
    c = a * b;
}

void muestra_loop(int &a, int &b, int &c) {
    std::cout << '\n' << a << " * " << b << " = " << c << '\n';
}
```

Lo vemos [[en un ejemplo]](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/o1pVOzhLT1RSm0wf):

```
int main()
{
    int a{}, b{}, c{};

    operador s{ lee_suma, suma, muestra_suma };
    operador l{ lee_loop, loop, muestra_loop };

    std::cout << "Voy a usar el operador s.\n";
    s.leer(a, b, c);
    s.calculo(a, b, c);
    s.escribir(a, b, c);

    // Anulación <---- 
    std::cout << "Ahora anulo s (suma) con l (loop).\n";
    s = l; // <---- Se supone que así anulo las funciones del objeto s
           //       y le asigno las funciones del objeto l
    s.leer(a, b, c);
    s.calculo(a, b, c);
    s.escribir(a, b, c);

    return{};
}
```

Dado que la firma de todas las funciones del operador son la misma, se podría haber usado un único tipo:

```
using opera = void(int &, int &, int &);

struct operador
{
    opera *leer;
    opera *calculo;
    opera *escribir;
};
```

También podría usarse la *anulación* o sobre-escritura así:

```
s = { lee_loop, loop, muestra_loop }; // Así anulo las funciones del objeto s
                                      // y le asigno funciones de loop
```

---

<sup>1</sup>En general, cualquier herramienta de programación (como la herencia y/o la memoria dinámica) debe ser usada sólo cuando sean necesario, de otra manera podría llegar a considerarse [sobreingeniería](http://blogingenieria.com/general/problema-sobreingenieria/). Podemos discutir si en este caso la herencia y sobre-escritura de métodos era la herramienta adecuada o no.

Comment: Eso de que usamos la memoria dinámica... el último ejemplo de mi respuesta no tiene nada de memoria dinámica :). Lo que pasa es que el polimorfismo (concepto que menciona en el título de la pregunta) suele implicar memoria dinámica porque tener polimorfismo con objetos en la pila suele ser peligroso y complicado

Comment: @eferion cierto, no me fijé que en el último ejemplo usas objetos del contexto en lugar de crearlos dinámicamente; sin embargo no te libras de los "*pecados*" de usar punteros y herencia; tan sólo quise aportar una solución diferente a las ya existentes que además coincide con la sintáxis que puso akko en su hilo :)

Answer (score 2):

1- Para poder sobre-escribir un método, lo debes declarar como `virtual` en la clase padre:

```
class suma{
    public:
        virtual void leer(int &a, int &b, int &c);
        virtual void calculo(int &a, int &b, int &c);
        virtual void escribir(int &a, int &b, int &c);
};
```

2- Declarando los objetos como objetos, no funcionan los métodos virtuales. Deberás usar un puntero o una referencia. Ejemplo:

```
suma *s = new suma();
loop *l = new loop();

// Anulación <----
cout << "Los punteros si permiten sobreescribir los metodos virtuales." << endl;

s = l; // Ahora si funciona por que es un puntero al objeto.

s->leer(a, b, c);
s->calculo(a, b, c);
s->escribir(a, b, c);
```

No olvides hacer `delete` de los objetos creados con `new`.

Comment: Muchas gracias, pero lo que intento hacer es diferente a virtualización.

Comment: Lo que intentas hacer se hace con métodos virtuales, de otro modo no funcionara.

Answer (score 0):

En ensamblador, de intel o del procesador que sea, siempre hay una operación llamada "CALL".

Esa CALL va a acompañada de un parametro, que puede ser una constante (una direccion de memoria constante escrita en "flujo de codigo" justo despues de CALL), o bien "algo variable" como. p.e. el valor de un registro del procesador.

En tu ejemplo, al no haber metodos virtuales (ni querer como dices trabajar con metodos virtuales), la linea "s.leer" genera en ensamblador (e independiente de las lineas anteriores), un:

CALL "dir_cte_memoria"

siendo  la direccion que le asigna a la funcion "suma.leer".

Sin embargo cuando se usan metodos virtuales, se genera algo parecido a esto:

CALL [EBX]

"vete a la dir de memoria contenida en el registro ebx",
lo cual es un poco más ineficiente, pero muy poco más. Pero permite "calls" dinamicos.

RESUMIENDO, sin "virtual", es imposible hacer CALL mas allá del suma.leer, ya que "leer" no es "dinamico" (es decir virtual).